# White screen on Diskstation after updating to DSM 5.0-4458

Tags: synology

This morning I updated my diskstation to DSM 5.0-4458. After the reboot I tried to login with quickconnect. After typing my username and password I get a white screen. Other browsers and clearing the cache doesn't work.
I can still connect with SSH and I still have all my files.

How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried rebooting the NAS? Also, try restarting the web services through SSH.

Comment: I did  ash S97apache-sys.sh restart, didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Also did a hard reset, didn't solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i solved the issue: 
I have a DS413j NAS. I couldn't access the NAS anymore. After login from browser, there was a white screen  or loading screen. I did a hard reset to solve issue, but this was a bad idea. I completely locked myself out. There was no SSH access because the admin and root user password was resetted and you need activate the SSH access again within the interface. You could solve this problem with a new hard drive so you wont lose your data, or you would format the hard drive. (I lost all my data)

Take HDD out, format it, make one new volume. Then you need to plug in your hard drive in your NAS again. Disconnect all other drives. Contact Synology assistance, find your NAS and press install.
He will ask for an installation file for your version of the DSM. You can't install an older version because it does a version check based on the filename.

After your system is up and running, you can download the previous version that you would like to install. From the download center: 
https://www.synology.com/en-us/support/download/DS413j

I have downloaded: 
DSM_DS413j_4493.pat 
And changed the name to "recovery-image.bin.pat".

The installation will now continue, after this, your NAS will have the old version.

#### Very Important:

Turn off automatic updates so the Synology team can't mess your system up again! 
Biggest waste of time and money!